# ASP.Net web api token authentication is suitable to secure financial API to stop abuse?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api2, token, bearer-token

I have a secure financial API, where the user generates a token with a request to `/token`. Tokens work fine with the API, even when using SSL also; however, many people keep on generating new tokens even though an existing token is already active for them. Some are using tokens from two or more IPs.

Can we create any custom filter or check IP address/user while calling a resource that to check if it is the same IP for which a token was issued?

Comment: you can do that by tracking the tokens and the ip on a server database

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, then update your answer.

Comment: why ! ... use of database will defeat purpose of token .. is there any way to do it somehow without db .... using cookie validation or something?

Comment: Even if I track token and ip in server database, when I can remove token, I mean how to capture event of token becoming invalid(expired) ?